# How to get the latest security updates for CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, security

I have installed CyanogenMod in February 2016, and the device information showed Android version "5.1.1", and the security patch level was "November 2015".

This hasn't changed until today (2016-02-20): The device says that there are no updates.

Looking at http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog the last entry with "Android Security Bulletin" in the title was back in October 2015.

Looking at https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/index.html there are security bulletins for each month.

So my question is: How can I get these Android security updates for CyanogenMod?

Any information about that delay (if it's really one) is appreciated as well.
It's OK if have to compile it myself.

In case it's device specific: I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini.

**Update**

I have probably used the "Download latest release" link on the page pointed out by xangua in his answer, and it seems that this link in fact refers to a "snapshot". I am looking for security patches for the "latest release" (v12).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't updated in a long time as at today (2016-02-20) latest nighty for that device is cm13.0 2016-02-19.

If you refer however to a snapshot, as you can see the latest available one is from November.

[https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=serranoltexx](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=serranoltexx&type=)

Comment: I see. Do I have to switch to the current version (v13) to get security patches? In other words: are there security backports from v13 to v12 at all? I just want to have a working and secure smartphone - is v13 already stable?

Comment: Switch or not is up to you, also unless you specific what exactly you consider insecure the statesmen you want a"secure smartphone"is very unclear.

Comment: Regardless of switching from a snapshot to a nighty build, you'll have to make a clean install. Also it is the snapshot that is considered "stable" as the nighty build are.....built in a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install latest security patches on older android/cyanogen/lineage/etc versions.

You will have to upgrade to latest version for your device to get that.